# How to set debug host and port on android 8.1

Tags: android, react-native

I'm debugging my app via WiFi. It installs successfully but I got a red screen with an error:

[image: Could not connect to development server]

The documentation says that I should [set debug host and port](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device#method-2-connect-via-wi-fi) but there is no "Debug server host & port for device" menu entry. Also, my problem is similar to [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-react-native/issues/324).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- bring up the react native menu that is referenced in the link below
- start with debugging turned off (the menu should show `debug JS remotely` and not `stop debugging`).
- if the app is running with debugger, configure the debugging host and port: click on `dev settings` and type `localhost:8081`.
- now try to run the app while `npm start` or `yarn start` is running in the host's terminal window.

#### This is the menu:

https://process.filestackapi.com/cache=expiry:max/FAoXMWT3QJPYymUBYSOw

Comment: I did it. Thank you!

Comment: how to bring up the menu